# SDL Renderer not initating a window

Tags: c, sdl, renderer

I cant get the renderer window to show.Have any idea?

EDIT: everything compiles fine , but no window shows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
SDL_Window *win;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
int main(int argc ,char *argv[]){
  (void) argc;
  (void)argv;
  SDL_Event events;
  int x;
  int y;
  int w;
  int h;
  int running;
  
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
      SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "error %s\n", SDL_GetError());
      return -1;}
  x=60;
  y=60;
  w=800;
  h=600;
  win = SDL_CreateWindow("Fractale",
             x,y,w,h,
             SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  if (win==NULL)
    {
      SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
           "error :%s\n",SDL_GetError());
      SDL_Quit();
      return -1;}
 renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win,-1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
 if (renderer == NULL)
   {
     SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
          "error : %s\n" , SDL_GetError());
     SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
     SDL_Quit();
     return -1;}
 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,255,255,255);
 SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

 SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,0,0,255);
 SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, w / 2 ,h / 2);
 SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  
  running =1;
  while(running){
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&events))
      {
    switch (events.type)
      {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        running=0;
        break;
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch(events.key.keysym.sym)
          {
          case'q':
        running = 0;
        break;
          }
      }
      }
  }
  
 SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
SDL_Quit();
```

Comment: What do you expect `(void) argc;
  (void)argv;` to do?

Comment: i added them because i used to get a compilation eror along the lines of "unused argc/argv variable "

Comment: I recommend `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: Concerning your code editing problems. see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help I recommend the `\`\`\`\``version. While you are at it, apply some indentation please.

Comment: isn't argc argv variables obligatory for sdl to work?

Comment: For what? If it were obligatory to use them, you would have problems, because you don't.

Comment: Did you follow any tutorial or use any example code? Did you not find any SDL HelloWorld?

Comment: tried but the window still aint showing!

Comment: i actually used my teacher's exemple code for this , but i cant even get the results in the exercice despite following it to a T

Comment: See any error print outs? Does the program continue to run and "hang" or exit immediately? Could the window be minimized or off screen, on another monitor?

Comment: Your example works for me if I add `return 0; }` to the end of the code in your question.

Comment: there is no compilation erors i used to have a ton of them , it compiles smoothly with
" gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o sdl_test sdl_test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`"
in mingw , i have only one monitor and the window just doesnt show .Maybe i have to add a delay?

Comment: @RetiredNinja
okay let me try that .Do you get the window with the red dot in the midlle?

i actually have the return 0 in my own code but i still dont get the window , thats very werid maybe i have an installation issue with my mingw?

Comment: "I'm a beginner in C" You'll quickly learn that compiling smoothly makes no guarantees whatsoever of running smoothly. Compiling cleanly is just the start. The `if ( .. == NULL)` checks are for checking runtime problems. You haven't explicitly said it, but sounds like none of those errors are happening.

Comment: @ousmm Yes, I see a window with a dot in the middle, although the dot is much easier to see if you use black as your clear color. You could also use `SDL_RenderDrawRect` or `SDL_RenderFillRect` to draw something a bit easier to see.

Comment: @yano yes i see absolutly no errors how can i check if the if(win==NULL) is the issue if the compilation runs smoothly?

Comment: @RetiredNinja 
ok thanks at least the code seems to run ok then i must have a minor mistake somewhere , thats really helpfull.

Comment: `if(win == NULL)` then you should see an error message (where ever the SDL log is ..?) and the program should immediately quit (because of the `return -1;`). If your program doesn't immediately exit, you just don't see a window, then it appears neither `win` nor `renderer` are NULL. You could step through with a debugger to be sure.

Comment: @Yunnosch SDL does require `argc`, `argv` to be present (on some platforms, notably Windows), because it re`#define`s `main` to something else, and then calls the resulting function from its own `main`, passing two arguments.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Now that you mention it.... I do remember something like that. Thanks.

Comment: @ousmm check the terminal output and program run duration like yano said. Move your rendering to `while(running)` loop (i.e. crear and draw after events processing).

Comment: @Yunnosch the reasons for that are C++ name mangling and function overloading, while question is tagged as `C`, so shouldn't matter in that case. But of course that function argument change wouldn't solve original problem.